# Deployment en Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Estoy intentando subir un proyecto python a heroku pero he estado teniendo problemas, según entiendo para subir un proyecto a heroku es necesario que este utilizando flask o django, pero la verdad no quiero complicarme ya que no se nada de esos framework. Mi proyecto funciona en consola, es un archivo `.py` normal uso graficas y librerías como `numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn`. una opcion que investigue es `voila` ya que tengo un `jupyter-notebook` pero he visto comentarios de que no funciona con heroku.

Asi que algun consejo o tendre que usar obligatoriamente flask o django

Comment: Hola @Brigido,  que es lo que hace tu archivo.py y porque querrias deployarlo en heroku?

Comment: Hola @HernanAcosta el archivo toma un dataset y genero 4 graficas con los datos, acerca de porque querría deployarlo en heroku es un requisito del profesor solo eso

Comment: Bien en ese caso te envio este link que te puede ayudar. https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/deploy-jupyter-notebook-voila-heroku.html

Answer (score 1):

He subido un par de proyectos a Heroku. Es una plataforma para publicar aplicaciones web y esto implica que la interacción con el programa debe ocurrir a través de un navegador web en lugar de una consola.

Si lo que necesitas es tener en la web un código que recibe un dato, lo elabora y luego devuelve el resultado deberías considerar utilizar una tecnología diferente como por ejemplo [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/it/lambda/) de [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/it/) (Amazon Web Service).

De lo contrario, si lo que quieres es poder acceder a un terminal de comandos e interactuar con el programa en la web como lo haces en tu PC, esto no se puede hacer sin realizar una aplicación web con alguno de los frameworks que mencionas u otros, ya que los navegadores comunican en http y tienes que utilizar este protocolo en tu aplicación para poder interactuar con ellos además de realizar una interfaz amigable en HTML y CSS.

Si no logras con voila, te recomiendo usar Flask porque en comparación con Django trae menos funcionalidades preconfiguradas por defecto y para este proyecto eso es bueno ya que al parecer no necesitas una base de datos ni un sistema de autenticación, además Flask es más sencillo y rápido de entender/aprender y debido a todo esto es más usado en proyectos de baja o media complejidad.